Using matching column's value to create an expanded table
Suppose I have the following table. I want to put all the info into the same row (expand the table horizontally) when the value of the CallId is the same. Can it be done using a standard SQL?



CallId
Type
Region
Gender




0000001
Sender
North East
M


0000001
Receiver
South
F


0000002
Sender
Midwest
F


0000002
Receiver
Midwest
M


0000003
Sender
Midwest
M


0000003
Receiver
West
M


...
...
...
...



How would I create a table where



CallId
Region.Sender
Region.Receiver
Gender.Sender
Gender.Receiver




0000001
North East
South
M
F


0000002
Midwest
Midwest
F
M


0000003
Midwest
West
M
M


...
...
...
...
...




The answer is yes, it can be done. You can e.g. do a self (outer?) join, or a group by.

You can use conditional aggregation (aka a Pivot).
SELECT
  t.CallId,
  MAX(IIF(t.Type = 'Sender', t.Region, '')) AS Region_Sender,
  MAX(IIF(t.Type = 'Receiver', t.Region, '')) AS Region_Receiver,
  MAX(IIF(t.Type = 'Sender', t.Gender, '')) AS Gender_Sender,
  MAX(IIF(t.Type = 'Receiver', t.Gender, '')) AS Gender_Receiver
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY
  t.CallId;

In Postgres and other systems you can use the syntax MIN(t.Region) FILTER (WHERE t.Type = 'Sender)

Sorry for not mentioning it earlier but could you write a query that works in MSAccess? It doesn't seem to work as is. Thanks for the keywords of conditional aggregation (aka Pivot).

I think you'd need IIF here

When running the script as is, an error occurs: '"Region.Sender"' is not a valid name. Make sure it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long.. So I changed all the relevant . to _ (e.g.: "Region.Sender" -> "Region_Sender"). Also " seems unncessary (e.g.: Region.Sender -> Region_Sender). When I ran the code with those fixes, all cell for "Region_Sender" and Region_Sender columns are empty.

Use MAX instead

Changing from MIN to MAX worked. Thanks. One more thing, although I do not have Postgres to test, I think it is missing an apostrophe after the word Sender for the Postgres answer. Note: My comment above should have been all cell for Region_Sender and Gender_Sender columns are empty. (not all cell for "Region_Sender" and Region_Sender columns are empty.)

SELECT Sender.CallId, Receiver.Region_Receiver, Receiver.Gender_Receiver, Sender.Region_Sender, Sender.Gender_Sender
FROM (SELECT t.CallId, t.Region AS Region_Sender, t.Gender AS Gender_Sender
      FROM CallSession AS t
      WHERE t.Type = 'Sender')  AS Sender
INNER JOIN 
     (SELECT t.CallId, t.Region AS Region_Receiver, t.Gender AS Gender_Receiver
      FROM CallSession AS t
      WHERE t.Type = 'Receiver') AS Receiver
ON Sender.CallId = Receiver.CallId;

will produce



CallId
Region_Receiver
Gender_Receiver
Region_Sender
Gender_Sender




1
South
F
North East
M


2
Midwest
M
Midwest
F


3
West
M
Midwest
M


...
...
...
...
...



also changing Receiver.Region_Receiver to Receiver.[Region_Receiver] notation makes no difference.

TRANSFORM First(t.Region & "-" & t.Gender) AS Attributes
SELECT t.CallId
FROM CallSession AS t
GROUP BY t.CallId
PIVOT t.Type;

will produce



CallId
Receiver
Sender




1
South-F
North East-M


2
Midwest-M
Midwest-F


3
West-M
Midwest-M


...
...
...




How is this better than conditional aggregation? It requires an extra join so less efficient.

@Charlieface Thanks for pointing it out. I did not know. I voted yours up and accepted it as an answer. Thanks again.
